# Getting error on inserting tuple values in postgreSQL table using python

Tags: python, last.fm

I want to keep last.fm's user  recent music tracks list to postgresql database table using pylast interface.But when I tried to insert values to the table it shows errors.Code example:

```
import pylast
import psycopg2
import re
from md5 import md5
import sys
import codecs
import psycopg2.extensions

psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
user_name = raw_input("Enter last.fm username: ")
user_password = raw_input("Enter last.fm password: ")

api_key = '*********'
api_secret = '********'

#Lastfm network authentication
md5_user_password = md5(user_password).hexdigest()
network = pylast.get_lastfm_network(api_key, api_secret,user_name,md5_user_password)

used=pylast.User(user_name, network)

recent_tracks=used.get_recent_tracks(10)

# Database connection 
try:
    conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='**' user='postgres' host='localhost'   password='*'")
    conn.set_client_encoding('UNICODE')
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database, exiting."
    sys.exit()
cur=conn.cursor()

for i, artist in enumerate(recent_tracks):
    for key in sorted(artist):

        cur.execute("""
        INSERT INTO u_recent_track(Playback_date,Time_stamp,Track) 
        VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",  (key, artist[key]))

    conn.commit()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM u_recent_track;")
cur.fetchone()
for row in cur:
    print '   '.join(row[1:])

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Here "recent_tracks" tuple have the values for example:

```
artist 0
  - playback_date : 5 May 2010, 11:14
  - timestamp : 1273058099
  - track         : Brian Eno - Web
```

I want to store these value under u_recent_track(Tid, Playback_date, Time_stamp, Track).Can anybody have idea how to sort out this problem? when I tried to run, it shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\JavaWorkspace\Test\src\recent_track_database.py", line 50, in <module>
    VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",  (key, artist[key]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Hello I have edited with full code contents..!

Answer (score 1):

`sorted(artist)` returns a ordered list of artist, when you're iterating over it it returns still elements of `artist`. So when you're trying to access `artist[key]` it is actually trying to access an element of `artist` indexed by the index, which is an element of `artist` itself. Tuples do not work this way.

It seems you're using python2.5 or lower and therefore you could do:

```
cur.executemany("""
        INSERT INTO u_recent_track(Playback_date,Time_stamp,Track) 
        VALUES (%(playback_date)s,%(timestamp)s,%(track)s)""",  recent_tracks)
conn.commit()
```

This should work.

Comment: I have tried with that, but it reports like:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'playback_date'

but it has, I cant get that point :(

Comment: @rahman: use `dir(track)` to see what's inside the `track` variable.

Comment: @SilentGhost:
in track variable, using dir , I get :

['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__str__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']

Comment: @silentghost: I am using pylast-0.4.20 !

Comment: @silentghost: still error on :
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt

Comment: @rahman: look, each of the packages you're using either has excelent documentation or is written in plain python. you could also see what is required as an input with `help(cur.execute)` command. Docs for psycopg2 are here http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/ with examples, etc.

Comment: @silentghost: I was trying on this matter!..It doesn't help..!could you please look it back again?

Comment: @rahman: you need to establish what is actually not working and what is contained in `recent_tracks`. I'll fix typo in a sec.

Comment: "recent_tracks" is list variable.Which can hold track information
like playback_date , timestamp and track info from pylast interface.
you can look from below segment:
"used=pylast.User(user_name, network)
recent_tracks=used.get_recent_tracks(10)"

And now I cant get those user information about track in database table  I have shown in the code! it shows "psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt" 
after editing my code suggested by you! It is badly needed to resolve :(

Comment: @silentghost: I have another script relating to get recent_tracks which is working to user information, out put sample is like :

artist 0
  - playback_date : 5 May 2010, 11:14
  - timestamp : 1273058099
  - track         : Brian Eno - Web
 So I want to keep these information in a table and retrieve from that.Thats why I made the above code script to do that..!

Comment: @rahman: can you get anything into that table? I fixed that typo. It should work now.

Comment: @Silentghost: Unfortunately not! What typo you fixed? was it timestampe to timestap! same error!..

Comment: @silentghost : could you please look that again as it seems it doesn't insert user track data to the database table yet :(

Comment: @rahman: create a simple working test, that would insert a record using `cursor.execute` and the query I've provided. `recent_tracks` should be a simple dictionary with three elements. If that doesn't work, then your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`(Playback_date,Time_stamp,Track)` indicates you want to insert three values into a row.
`VALUES (%s,%s)` should therefore be `VALUES (%s,%s,%s)`
and `(key, artist[key])` should be a tuple with 3 elements, not 2.

Try:

```
for track in recent_tracks:
    cur.execute("""
        INSERT INTO u_recent_track(Playback_date,Time_stamp,Track) 
        VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""",  (track.get_date(), track.get_timestamp(), track.get_track()))
    conn.commit()
```

PS. [This is where](http://pondsideweb.com/webservices/lastfm/pylast.html#PlayedTrack) I'm getting my information about the pylast API.

PPS. If my reading of the documentation is correct, `track.get_track()` will return a `Track` object. It has methods like `get_album`, `get_artist`, `get_id` and `get_title`. Exactly what do you want stored in the `Track` column of the `u_recent_track` database table?

Comment: @unutbu: recent-tracks are from pylast user class!..it cant help more! :(

Answer (score 0):

This error isn't anything to do with Postgres, but with the `artist` variable. You're firstly saying:

```
for key in sorted(artist):
```

implying that it's a list, but then you're accessing it as if it were a dictionary, which is raising an error. Which is it? Can you show an example of the full contents?

Comment: Well, I have edited my code with full contents.can you please look whats the heck here ? Thanks in advanced!